# What do you mean I didn't declare 'exit' in scope?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to compile an old C++ codebase, not written by me, and I'm getting the following error:

`'exit' was not declared in scope.`

The code that's giving me the error is at the top of the text, and looks like this:

```
%{

#include "AppHdr.h"
#include "libutil.h"
#include "levcomp.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int yylex();

extern int yylineno;

void yyerror(const char *e)
{
    std::fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: %s\n", lc_desfile.c_str(), yylineno, e);
    // Bail bail bail.
    std::exit(1);
}
```

Apparently this issue is related to changes in the compiler (`g++`) the makefile invokes. I believe I should be solve this problem by putting an `#include <cstdlib>`) *somewhere* in the file, so that's what I've been trying... but no matter where I put it -- before the `%{`, with the rest of the `#include`s, inside the `yyerror()` function itself -- nothing works.

What's going on, and how do I fix this and future errors like this, preferably tampering with as little of the codebase as possible?

EDIT: Oh, and here's my output from `g++ --version`:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If it matters, this is a .ypp file.

Comment: Learn about the `std` namespace.

Comment: `exit()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, so add an `#include` for that. `fprintf()` is declared in `<stdio.h>`, so add an `#include` for that as well.  If you use `<c...>` instead of `<...h>`, you will have to prefix the functions with `std::`, or add a `using namespace std;` statement.

Comment: I find this reference very helpful http://en.cppreference.com/

Comment: Hmm, it's still giving me problems. I've tried putting `#include <cstdlib>`, `#include <stdlib>`, `#include <stdlib.h>`, and `#include <cstdlib.h>` in all the places I mentioned before, and none of them are working. The error hasn't changed, either. With and without both `using namspace std` and `std::`, both individually and together.

Comment: I did research. It wasn't a blind guess. Everything I found told me that I needed to `#include <cstdlib>` those, when my problem is that even _when_ I include those, it spits out the same error.

Comment: Still no success. I updated the OP to show what I'm doing. Can anyone tell my what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `-std=c++03` and `-std=c++11`? If you still have the error, would put entire code (or slim down) so we could compile?